# remove subview from UIScrollview shows white space

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

When trying to remove single subview from `UIScrollView`'s `subview`. its not giving good result.

1. `UIScrollView` added in Interface builder with `autolayout`

   ```
   NSInteger numberOfViews = 15;
   for (NSUInteger x=0; x<numberOfViews; x++) {

      CGRect rect = CGRectMake(xPosition,-[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, self.view.frame.size.height + [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height);
      UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

      imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor magentaColor];  
      imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
      imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
      imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
      imageView.tag = x;
      [_scrollView addSubview:imageView];

      xPosition += [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
   }

   _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width * numberOfViews, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
   _scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
   ```
2. My Code to remove single `subview`

   ```
   // identifying current page

   int page = _scrollView.contentOffset.x / _scrollView.frame.size.width;

    for(UIImageView *subview in [_scrollView subviews]) {
       if(subview.tag == page)
       {
           NSLog(@"imageview remove with tag: %ld",(long)subview.tag);
           [subview removeFromSuperview];

           _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width * [[_scrollView subviews] count], [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
           [_scrollView setNeedsDisplay];
           [_scrollView setNeedsLayout];
           [_scrollView reloadInputViews];

           [_allUsersData removeObjectAtIndex:page];
           CGPoint offset = _scrollView.contentOffset;
           CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(offset.x+self.view.frame.size.width, offset.y);
           [_scrollView setContentOffset:newOffset animated:YES];
       }
   }
   ```

it shows black white space. can you correct me where aim doing wrong.

Comment: What is page ? and where did u declare it ?

Comment: Are you sure page is int not float ? When you use / it returns float, you either cast it to int or convert the result to int !!!

Answer (score 0):

You have added your views once and have defined frames for them. Now when you remove any of your subview, you just remove it but the rest of the subviews that comes  after the subview that is being removed, have the old frames that has been set initially.

In your remove subview code, log the following in your if block

```
 NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(subview.frame));
 UIImageView *nextView = [_scrollView viewWithTag:page+1];
 NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(nextView.frame));
 .....
 .....
 CGPoint offset = _scrollView.contentOffset;
 CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(offset.x+self.frame.size.width, offset.y);
 [_scrollView setContentOffset:newOffset animated:YES];
 NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(nextView.frame));
```

You will notice that the 'nextView' has the same frame before and after deletion of a subview. Your desired view has been removed correctly hence giving you a blank white space as you have cleared the background colour of scrollview, but the rest of subview's frame are not updated.

Also don't use scrollview subview count when setting content size as scrollview has its own subviews like scroll indicator, instead use your own viewTobeAdded count otherwise it will give you extra space in the end.

Change this

```
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width * [[_scrollView subviews] count], [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
```

To this

```
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width * YourViewsCount, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
```

Comment: I pointed out  the issue that causing the white space problem, you need to update the frames by  yourself. As far as the scrollview  content size code  is concerned that was an additional information, you can test that extra space scenario.

Comment: can you guide me on how to update frames also? it will be big help

Answer (score 0):

There must be some dataSource using which you are populating your subviews in scrollView. For instance i suppose that 'numberOfViews' is your source for now.

```
-(void)updateViewsAfterPage:(int)page{

for(int start = page  ;start < numberOfViews ; start ++) {
    id subview = [_scrollView viewWithTag:start + 1];

    if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        CGRect newFrame = [(UIImageView*)subview frame];
        newFrame.origin.x = start * [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;

        [(UIImageView*)subview setTag:start];
        [(UIImageView*)subview setFrame:newFrame];
    }
}}
```

Above is the method for updating rest of views.Call this method after removing subview from scrollView and updating dataSource.i.e.

```
[subview removeFromSuperview];
numberOfViews -- ;
[self updateViewsAfterPage:page];
.... // update scrollview content size
break;
```

Hope it helps!

P.S. Try not to use 'viewWithTag' method as this might give you wrong view if there is some other view with same tag in hierarchy and also this is not recommended by Apple.